# I don't understand how to use Modulus

Tags: modulus

I am brand new to coding and I am having a lot of trouble just getting this to work:

Declare 2 integer variables.  Prompt the user for two numbers. 
Store the values into variables using the Scanner object.
If the second number is a multiple of the first number, display " is a multiple of ".  Otherwise display " is not a multiple of "

I have this code below then i am lost:

```
int number1, number2;
System.out.println("Enter a number:");
number1 = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
number2 = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulus is the remainder of dividing 2 numbers. If number2 is a multiple of number1, dividing them will have a remainder 0, otherwise not.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number1, number2;
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        number1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
        number2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        int mod = number2 % number1;

        if (mod == 0) {
            System.out.println(number2 + " is a multiple of " + number1);
        } else { 
            System.out.println(number2 + " is not a multiple of " + number1);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulus simply gives you the remainder of the division of two numbers. For eg : 4/3 gives the remainder as 1 similarly in programmatic way you can try 4%3 which two will give the same response. Added a python code snippet below :

```
a = int(input("Enter first no."))
b = int(input("Enter second no."))
print("Modulus operation a%b gives : ", (a % b))
print("Is ", a, " multiple of ", b)
print((a%b) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If number1 is a multiple of number2 than it will devide number2 with remainder 0,
 for ex if 4 is multiple of 2 than 4%2==0, is true ,
 here % is modulus operator that returns remainter of the division of two numbers :::

In your case if number1 is multiple of number2  than
Number1%number2==0 (must);

Than your program should be like this:

```
If(number1%number2==0)
{
System.out.println("number1 is a multiple of number 2");
 }
Else
 System.out.println("not a multiple");
```

Answer (score 0):

> i am lost

Suppose you are in a competition to eat chocolates and the rule is:

**Eat three chocolates at the same time**

If you are given:

```
1 chocolate,  you will not eat, and 1 chocolate  will be left
2 chocolates, you will not eat, and 2 chocolates will be left
3 chocolates, you eat once,     and 0 chocolates will be left
4 chocolates, you eat once,     and 1 chocolate  will be left
5 chocolates, you eat once,     and 2 chocolates will be left
6 chocolates, you eat twice,    and 0 chocolates will be left
7 chocolates, you eat twice,    and 1 chocolate  will be left
...
100 chocolates, you eat 33 times, 1 chocolate will be left
...
1502 chocolates, you eat 500 times, 2 chocolates will be left
```

The number of chocolates left each time is called **Modulus** is Mathematics, a powerful operation in computers.

As you can tell, you will always be left with less than 3 chocolates (`0` or `1` or `2`) anytime.

Hence, `x modulus y` is always less than `y` in the range `0` to `y-1`.

In programming, the `modulus` operator is `%`.

So, if we write the way you ate chocolates using the `modulus` operator `%`, it looks like:

```
1 % 3  =  1
2 % 3  =  2
3 % 3  =  0
4 % 3  =  1
5 % 3  =  2
6 % 3  =  0
7 % 3  =  1
...
100 % 3  =  1
...
1502 % 3  =  2
```

Now tell me, are you lost?